# v-forのデータ追加時の挙動

Tags: javascript, vue.js

HTML側で、v-forループ表示してるtestListという配列があります。
初期表示は20件で、ユーザが「次の20件」というボタンを押下時に
testListにデータが20件追加されます。
この場合testListの描画は下記のどちらになるのでしょうか？

1. 1~40件まで全て再描画
2. 20~40件までが追加描画される

また、1であった場合どのようにしたら2の挙動にできるか
参考になるようなものをご存知でしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「再描画」というのがどのような意味かによりますが、「DOM elementがいったん削除されて新しいのが挿入される」という意味なら、今の場合されません。

[key - Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)を見ると、デフォルト(`key`なし)ではin-placeに各elementを更新すると書いてあります。今の場合だと1-20件のelementは、削除・挿入はされません。

また、`key`属性を指定した場合は、配列が更新されると`key`を元に並び替え・削除・挿入が発生します。testListにデータが20件追加されるときに、前の20件の`key`が変わらないのであれば、その中では削除・挿入は発生しません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「再描画」とは1−20のＤＯＭが

Comment: コメントが途中で切れてますよ。

Comment: コメント失礼いたしました。再描画とは1-20件ののDOMが再作成されるかということです。おっしゃる通り追加の21-40件のDOMが追加描画になり、1-20件はそのままでした。ありがとうございました！